# How do you call a subroutine from a package, given the package name in Perl?

Tags: perl, reflection, methods, package

Given a variable containing a string that represents the name of a package, how do I call a specific subroutine of the package?

Here's the closest thing I have figured out:

```
package MyPackage;

sub echo {
    print shift;
}

my $package_name = 'MyPackage';
$package_name->echo('Hello World');

1;
```

The problem with this code is the subroutine is called as a class method; the package name is passed in as the first argument. I want to invoke the subroutine from the package name without a special first argument being implicitly passed in.

Comment: If you don't want to pass an invocant, then what you want isn't to call a *method*.

Comment: @hobbs: Thanks. I've updated the question to use more correct terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl method calls are just regular subroutines, which get the invocant as the first value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

{
  package MyPackage;
  sub new{ bless {}, shift } # overly simplistic constructor (DO NOT REUSE)
  sub echo{ say @_ }
}

my $package_name = 'MyPackage';
$package_name->echo;

my $object = $package_name->new();
$object->echo; # effectively the same as MyPackage::echo($object)
```

```
MyPackage
MyPackage=HASH(0x1e2a070)
```

---

If you want to call a subroutine without an invocant, you will need to call it differently.

```
{
  no strict 'refs';
  ${$package_name.'::'}{echo}->('Hello World');
  &{$package_name.'::echo'}('Hello World');
}

# only works for packages without :: in the name
$::{$package_name.'::'}{echo}->('Hello World');

$package_name->can('echo')->('Hello World');
```

- The [`can`](https://metacpan.org/module/UNIVERSAL#obj-can-METHOD-) method returns a reference to the subroutine that would be called if it had been called on the invocant. The coderef can then be used separately.

  ```
  my $code_ref = $package_name->can('echo');
  $code_ref->('Hello World');
  ```

  There are some caveats to using [`can`](https://metacpan.org/module/UNIVERSAL#obj-can-METHOD-):

  - `can` may be overridden by the package, or any class from which it inherits.
  - The package that defines a method may be different than the invocant.

  This may actually be the behaviour you're looking for though.
- Another approach is to use something called a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references).

  ```
  {
    no strict 'refs';
    &{ $package_name.'::echo' }('Hello World');
  }
  ```

  Using symbolic references is usually not recommended. Part of the problem is that it is possible to accidently use a symbolic reference where you didn't intend on using one. This is why you can't have `use strict 'refs';` in effect.

  This may be the simplest way to do what you want to do though.
- If you don't want to use a symbolic reference you could use the [Stash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Stashes-and-Globs).

  ```
  $MyPackage::{echo}->('Hello World');
  $::{'MyPackage::'}{echo}->('Hello World');

  $main::{'MyPackage::'}{echo}->('Hello World');
  $main::{'main::'}{'MyPackage::'}{echo}->('Hello World');
  $main::{'main::'}{'main::'}{'main::'}{'MyPackage::'}{echo}->('Hello World');
  ```

  The only problem with this is that you would have to split `$package_name` on `::`

  ```
  *Some::Long::Package::Name::echo = \&MyPackage::echo;

  $::{'Some::'}{'Long::'}{'Package::'}{'Name::'}{echo}('Hello World');

  sub get_package_stash{
    my $package = shift.'::';
    my @package = split /(?<=::)/, $package;
    my $stash = \%:: ;
    $stash = $stash->{$_} for @package;
    return $stash;
  }
  get_package_stash('Some::Long::Package::Name')->{echo}('Hello World');
  ```

  This isn't that big of a problem though. After a quick look on [CPAN](http://cpan.org) you find [Package::Stash](http://p3rl.org/Package%3a%3aStash).

  ```
  use Package::Stash;
  my $stash = Package::Stash->new($package_name);
  my $coderef = $stash->get_symbol('&echo');
  $coderef->('Hello World');
  ```

  (The [Pure Perl](http://p3rl.org/Package%3a%3aStash%3a%3aPP) version of [Package::Stash](http://p3rl.org/Package%3a%3aStash) uses symbolic references, not the Stash)

---

It's even possible to make an alias of the subroutine/method, as if had been imported from a module that was using [Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Exporter):

```
*echo = \&{$package_name.'::echo'};
echo('Hello World');
```

I would recommend limiting the scope of the alias though:

```
{
  local *echo = \&{$package_name.'::echo'};
  echo('Hello World');
}
```

This is an exception, where you can use a symbolic reference with `strict 'refs'` enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I've accepted it because you provided a variety of ways to do what I asked. I particularly like the 'can' approach.

Comment: @Sam, `can` is wrong. It checks the inheritance tree. `can` is for methods.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you don't want to actually call it as a method, but as a regular subroutine. In that case, you can use a symbolic reference:

```
my $package_name = 'MyPackage';
{ 
    no strict 'refs';
    &{ $package_name . '::echo' }( 'Hello World' );
}
```

Comment: If you use `$::{$package_name.'::'}{echo}` you don't need to use `no strict 'refs';`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&{ <EXPRESSION> }()` syntax of calling a sub whose name is the expression, as discussed in [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) when listing dereferencing operators:

> Admittedly, it's a little silly to use the curlies in this case, but the BLOCK can contain **any arbitrary expression**, in particular, subscripted expressions:
>
> ```
>   &{ $dispatch{$index} }(1,2,3); # call correct routine
> ```

Random practical example:

```
# Note no "use strict"!
use File::Slurp; 
my $p="File::Slurp"; 
@a=&{"${p}::read_file"}(".profile"); 
print $a[0];
```